# Sharing Access To jQuery a cross Script Tags using Laravel-Mix

Tags: jquery, es6-modules, laravel-mix, lighthouse, npm-package

I have laravel-mix installed and I have two java script files both with packages in. One is global.js for the entire site and one is page.js for just this page.

My intention is to reduce the load speed by including common packages is global and packages only used on the page in page.js.

Both files have packages in that require jQuery but my first attempt failed when I added the following to the top of both files.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

But the second script files packages fail to initialise and when called come out as undefined.

When the script files were combined into one it worked well so there can't be a mistake with the package or its use.

Do I need to change how it is defined in one or both files.

Any help appreciated.

The reason for this is trying to get low Page Load Indexs in Lighthouse a cross the site.